# Progress bar in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Python code to run the progress bar on macOS Big Sur here (I copied it from an online tutorial):

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo


# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x120')
root.title('Progressbar Demo')


def update_progress_label():
    return f"Current Progress: {pb['value']}%"


def progress():
    if pb['value'] &lt; 100:
        pb['value'] += 20
        value_label['text'] = update_progress_label()
    else:
        showinfo(message='The progress completed!')


def stop():
    pb.stop()
    value_label['text'] = update_progress_label()


# progressbar
pb = ttk.Progressbar(
    root,
    orient='horizontal',
    mode='determinate',
    length=280
)
# place the progressbar
pb.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)

# label
value_label = ttk.Label(root, text=update_progress_label())
value_label.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2)

# start button
start_button = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text='Progress',
    command=progress
)
start_button.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.E)

stop_button = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text='Stop',
    command=stop
)
stop_button.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)


root.mainloop()
```

But when I run it, I received this error:

```
if pb['value'] &lt; 100:
                  ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How can I fix it? If I delete the ; it won't be able to run anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this: ```if pb['value'] &lt; 100:```? From where did you copy it? Change it do ```if pb['value']<100:```

Comment: I didn't remember exactly where did I copy it

Comment: However thank you so much for helping me. It worked

Comment: Most welcome. Happy to hear that :)

Comment: `&lt;` is an HTML entity that should appear as a less-than sign on a web page. This is not Python specific, but rather a typo in the tutorial (`&amp;lt;`).